# Making objects for each button

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I need to make objects for my buttons in my typing tutor.

I have made a class:

```
public class KeyLabel extends JLabel {

    public KeyLabel(String name) {
        setText(name); 

}
```

this is my subclass

my superclass is the keyboard class

and I need to make objects for each button on my keyboard for my typing tutor, so the a is a label its the keyboard

but I don't know how to do this?

Comment: why you create Label when you can set the text on button using setText() of JButton class

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why are you extending JLabel if you are to create Buttons. Extending JLabel will create a JLabel which will be wasted as in your code. More relavent code would be like

```
public class KeyLabel {

    public KeyLabel(String name) {

JButton buttonOK = new JButton("OK"); //creates OK button
}

}
```

Moreover, i think you should look [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html), for details.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, you'll want to use inheritance (i.e. subclass `JButton`). For instance,

```
public abstract JKeyboardButton extends JButton{
    public JKeyboardButton(final String key){
        super(key);
        // include other stuff, if necessary
    }

    // include other methods common to all JKeyboardButton instances
}
```

And then for each concrete button, you'll want to subclass `JKeyboardButton`, like so

```
public final class JKeyboardAButton extends JKeyboardButton{
    public JKeyboardAButton(){
        super("a");
    }

    // override/implement other methods..
}
```

And then in order to obtain a keyboard key of, let's say `a`, all you have to do is create an instance of `JKeyboardAButton`, like so

```
final JKeyboardButton aButton = new JKeyboardAButton();
```

And then obviously you'll have to create a class for each key and throw all these instances into a `Keyboard` class. But I'll leave the "heavier" coding to you.

Also, please note that the `final` modifier is not required, but rather is a personal preference of mine (i.e. to prevent subclassing and to ensure that a variable (even local ones) are only assigned once).

Comment: 'In most cases, you'll want to use inheritance' - actually no, you would _never_ use inheritance when you can get the same effect with configuration ... All JSomething (except the base class) are meant for _using_